# Eclipse ADT can't create Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, adt

Eclipse worked just fine until I installed the Google Play APIs, because I wanted to use the Maps API, and now suddenly, I can't create a new activity. I go to the new Android Activity wizard, everything's there, but after I click on the finish tab, no new activity appears. 
I've tried the "Install New Software" trick, it did nothing, and now when I try to install the package from [here](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse), I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

Is there a way to be able to use the add Android Activity wizard again without drastically changing everything? 
My ADT version is 23.0.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an API key defined in your manifest?  I know that is required for the Maps API.

Comment: Yes, I do, the problem is not the API, but I can't create a new activity whatsoever via the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need update **Android Developer Tools or the Latest Android SDK**:

Go to Menu : "`Help`" > "`Install New software...`" and add this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: As explained in the first post, I tried that and got the error shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with the same version 23.0.0. It looks like this is a bug that tends to come back in some releases, it already happen in the past. I would recommend that you downgrade your ADT to version 22.6.3.

You can download it from here: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.3.zip
After removing the most recent ADT from Eclipse, you can install the 22.6.3 version by following Google instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt

I know this is not the best solution, but until they released a fix, I think it's the best workaround without messing anything.

EDIT: update 23.0.2 was released and it should fix this issue.